# Choosing right artifact name

Tags: android, bouncycastle

I would like to use `SSL` in my Android Java application. For this reason I add `Group ID   org.bouncycastle` module. I got list of modules. How to choose right one? What logic I should go in order to select right `Artifact Name`?

[image]

Comment: Bouncycastle is a pure Java implementation, if you want to use OpenSSL then this is the wrong way. Search for `bcprov-jdk*` version, that is the base JAR file. The other are usually extensions to themain jar. The main download page also contains more description on the different versions: https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Comment: I have corrected mistake openssl->ssl. I need Bouncycastle, but have no idea which artifact name I should choose.

Comment: Simple approach: go to the download page I have linked to, scroll down to the table of available versions and use the first one. That would be `bcprov-jdk18on-173.jar` It is the `prov` = Provider = Base version for java 1.8+ (matches Android requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the correct BouncyCastle version isn't that complicated as it looks at a first glance.

### Filtering old Java versions

BouncyCastle has quite a history and for this reason there are still versions available for outdated Java versions. The target Java version is denoted in the middle starting with `-jdk...-`, e.g. `bcprov-jdk12-173.jar` - this is the version for Java 1.2 so you can safely ignore it. Also the Versions for pre Java 8 are no longer maintained, so you don't get the latest BouncyCastle version.

The newest JDK version for Java 8+, denoted as `...-jdk18on` in the artifact/download file names. This is the version you should choose.

### BouncyCastle type

There are two base types The "Standard" BouncyCastle provider implementation `bcprov-` and the "Extended" BouncyCastle provider `bcprov-ext-`.

The Extended version still contains deprecated and insecure algorithms that had been removed from the "Standard" version.

In next to all cases the "Standard" version should be the correct one for you.

All the other names like `bcutil-`, `bcpkix-`, `bcmail-` ... are special libraries that can base on BouncyCastle provider and extend the functionality for special purposes like S/MME, PGP,... Most users don't need this.

### Combining everything.

So you should use the "Standard" provider version for Java 8+.

Combining both you get the name `bcprov-jdk18on` and thus the following artifacts: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on